# How write input and output generic parameter for interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Help me plz with generics

I'm trying to make an interface with methods and I don't understand how to set input and output parameter for interfaces

i have a class with method

```
public TeachersDto[] MapToDto(Teachers[] entities, Dictionary<string, ParameterData> data)

public Teachers[] MapDto(TeachersDto dto, Dictionary<string, ParameterData> Data)
```

i try

```
public interface ITeachersMapper<RInput, Dictionary<string, RInput2>, TOutput>
{
    TDto[] MapToDto(TEntity[] entities, Dictionary<string, TInput> data);

    TEntity[] MapDto(TDto[] dtos, Dictionary<string, TInput> data);

}
```

How write input and output generic parameter for interface?

Comment: **R**Input vs **T**Input ? You are not using RInput, but TInput. For starters.

Comment: what do you mean?...i don't know how to describe correctly T in interface. each method will have different models: Teachers, TeachersDto, Parameter Data and a string (probably should also be replaced with a generic?)

Comment: Let's start one step back: So you want to map instances of some Type , let's call it "TEntity" to some type "TDto" and back, correct? That means that the two Methods should have different return types. Namely "TEntity[]" and "TDto" respective. Then what's the purpose of that Dictionary?

Comment: ... and what's your goal? Get the Generics fixed or have a Mapper? In the latter case, I'd suggest to use for example AutoMapper or some other mapping lib.

Comment: in the dictionary there is a date for the fields of models. field name and value

Comment: I corrected the class a little, it remains to understand what is happening with TInput

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me, yet. But to get your interface to compile, you should be good to go with `public interface ITeachersMapper<TInput, RInput2, TOutput>` - but you shouldn't name the interface I**Teachers**Mapper, when it is in fact generic. (The typenames refer to example code before the edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear how you are trying to use this interface since your interface doesn't match with your implementation that you give in the question, but I think this is what you are looking for.

Keep in mind that generic parameters can be called whatever you want, but `T` is just convention, so name your generic parameters something to make it obvious what they represent.

Also, you can't have a mixture of a specific type like Dictionary with a generic type. You can have a generic type with type constraints using where, but most likely you just want a generic type to define the `ParameterData` and don't need any of the Dictionary stuff in the generic specification.

I changed your classes to be just `Teacher` and `TeacherDto` since classes usually take a singular form.

```cs
    public interface IEntityMapper<TEntity, TParameterData, TDto>
    {
        TDto[] MapToDto(TEntity[] entities, Dictionary<string, TParameterData> data);
        TEntity[] MapDto(TDto[] dtos, Dictionary<string, TParameterData> data);
    }
    
    public class TeacherMapper : IEntityMapper<Teacher, ParameterData, TeacherDto>
    {
        public TeacherDto[] MapToDto(Teacher[] entities, Dictionary<string, ParameterData> data)
        {
            //..mapping to DTO here
        }
        public Teacher[] MapDto(TeacherDto[] dto, Dictionary<string, ParameterData> Data)
        {
            //..mapping to domain here
        }
    }
```

Comment: As I said in comments to the question: I'd also _not_ name the interface `ITeacherMapper` - it is not restricted to the `Teacher` class(es).

Comment: @Fildor good point, changed the interface to `IEntityMapper`